# GeckoFX invoke Javascript from c# for each element

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control, geckofx

Google adds a javascript method to each search result (hyperlink). 
Search any keyword from google, right click on a link, and copy link location or link address or just mouse down on a link and it will show the complete URL.

I need to simulate the onmousedown from c# to copy the complete link.

This is what Google render in HTML.

```
   <a href="http://www.canvaswallartprints.com.au/" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNE8fb_L5QLlY3a6lRhDbM2ZSp_UsA','','0CD4QFjAB','','',event)">Canvas Wall Art Prints » Products</a>
```

This link is shown on mouse down:

http://url/?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=webhp&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.canvaswallartprints.com.au%2Fproduct%2Fbonne-nuit%2F&ei=iQJtVZaBCsj8UKDqgMgE&usg=AFQjCNEAuSEgTR2_eYtjFFcXfNEHi8VVeA&bvm=bv.94455598,d.bGQ

There are lots of answers telling how to add events but in above case, the javascript function is already part of document, I just need to invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing my workaround to help if anyone else got stuck at same issue.
With GeckoFX I could not manage to invoke JavaScript method so, I had to move this part to WebBrowser control. Iterated HtmlElementCollection to reach the desired hyperlink and used the `HtmlElement InvokeMember("onmousedown")` to invoke the desired JavaScript function.